# Reportviewer1 not showing on vb 2010 express windows form application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

why does Reportviewer1 controls/toolbars not showing on vb 2010 express windows form application on my machine?

I have the Reportviewer.exe redistributable 2010 installed on my machine but every time I drag a reportviewer1 control on my form, nothing happens, I mean, nothing seen on my application form. Please help, I'm stuck and hopeless. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go on your .Designer.vb page and type/paste this code into the source view...

```
    //
    //ReportViewer1
    //
    Me.ReportViewer1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, -1)
    Me.ReportViewer1.Name = "ReportViewer1"
    Me.ReportViewer1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(396, 246)
    Me.ReportViewer1.TabIndex = 0
```

this should force your the declaration of a ReportViewer into your form.

**EDIT :**

While looking back at your question, do you have an icon for Reporting into your ToolBox? If so does a ReportViewer Object appears? If not you have to add it from VS2010 : Tools/ChooseToolboxItem/ and .NET framework componant. (maybe also elsewhere but mostly in this case) Choose any CrystalReport element you need.

Comment: you can also consider re-installing the package. It could not have been correctly installed....

Comment: yes sir ,  i have report viewer listed on the toolbox. Also , a report icon is seen on the bottom of the form.

Comment: You can try to do it by code. I mean a report is an Object, if you declare it as so and manipulate it correctly, you should be able to bypass this issue.

Comment: Thanks sir, if you don't mind can you please post a sample code on how to use the reportviewer .

Comment: From this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533291/crystal-reports-viewer-in-visual-studio-2010 . You could fix it.... If not working I will give you some code  to display a report with CR viewer.

Comment: Hello once again sir, as far as I know CR is not supported in Express edition

Comment: Ok, this in particular I did not know. And my VS is not express, so I am not sure any thing I try with my setting will work on yours... Sorry.

Comment: Sir, I really appreciate your support/ideas.. Honestly.  Thank you very much. . I am still working on my project with no reports, probably will be using Excel :) . As far as I have read, Reportviewer is already not supported in express edition. maybe, I should go for Ultimate. :-), Anyway sir, thank you once again. Your're great!!