# Opening Crystal Report Viewer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that I would like to open from a VB.net form. the Only problem is I'm having difficulties with finding out how to open up the Crystal Report Viewer from VB.net. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and I have the update for Crystal Reports which lets it be used in Visual Studio 2012. If anyone has any suggestions it would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You need to add the CrystalReportViewer on a form. After that dim a variable as ReportDocument, use Load() to get the RPT file and set it as source for the Viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to follow the steps listed here [Crystal Reports Viewer in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533291/crystal-reports-viewer-in-visual-studio-2010)
The only difference is that instead of going to the compile tab in the Project Designer, you go to the application tab