# Crystal report .rpt file opening in binary format instead of designer format

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008. While opening Crystal report .rpt file it shows some binary data instead of the designer file. I tried a lot of installs and uninstall for both 'VS2008' and the 'Crystal report basic for 2008'. But the issue isn't resolved yet.[image]

Anybody, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which .net framework are you on? i.e. `Project -> Properties -> Target Framework`

Comment: .NET framework 3.5

Comment: Standard or Client?

Comment: I think it is standard.

Comment: Can you check and be sure. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414791/3110695)

Comment: yes, it is standard. I can view the Crystal report viewer in the tool box. But the Crystal report editor option is missing while opening the .rpt file.

Answer (score 2):

For visual studio 2017 this worked for me

[SAP download guide](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads)

At one point says:

> For VS2017 integration, user needs use “run as Administrator” by right-clicking setup.exe, even if you are already log on by using Administrator account

So I downloaded [CRforVS_13_0_23.exe](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_23.exe) which is a self extracting file. Installing this the normal way didn't work.

I had to extract it with 7zip or such and run "setup.exe" as administrator.

After I was able to open .rpt files in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2022 has the same issue.  Like another poster I had to extract everything and run setup as administrator.  Also be sure to exit VS2022 before running setup - it won't warn you.

Comment: It is a valid point. I had previously installed it when my project was open. Why they didn't put warning don't know. Thanks @Rob

Comment: @NaitikKundalia there are no bugs, just unintended features.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late here but recently faced similar issue with VS2017 and CR13_0_23. I resolved the issue by installing CR service pack 21. Download service pack from https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

Answer (score -3):

You need to Uninstall Visual studio 2008 and again install fresh VS 2008. Because of I had also this issue.

Comment: OP said he already uninstall and reinstall VS2008 and your answer isn't really an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question as you have suggested the OP do something that he has already specified doing